# Django url parameter error

Tags: python, django

Here is my problem :

```
Using the URLconf defined in Rase.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

admin/
[name='index']
bio/<slug:username>/$ [name='bio']
The current path, bio/bussiere/, didn't match any of these.
```

the url is :

http://localhost:8000/bio/bussiere/

here is my url file  :

```
from django.urls import include, path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    path("bio/<slug:username>/$", views.bio, name='bio'),
]
```

If you have any idea ?

Thanks and regards

Comment: You probably used `url(..)` instead of `path(..)` when specifying the url. As a result, it takes `<slug:...` as *lterally part of the URL, not as meta-data. Can you share the `urlpatterns`?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem i've edited my post thanks

Comment: Remove the `$` at the end

Comment: @user462794: you should remove the `$` since that is a regex anchor, not a path specifier (or you should add a `$` to your URL :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using **Django 2.0.X** where url changed pretty much. You don't need to use regex for url when using `path()`  just remove the trailing ***$*** . So the url should be-

```
path("bio/<slug:username>/", views.bio, name='bio')
```